# Animations: How should I translate an ImageView out of/into visibility on the screen

Tags: android, animation

I am using a `translate` animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate
    android:fromXDelta="-75%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

on a basic `ImageView`.  This animation will slide the image out from the left until it reaches the right edge of the screen.  I have an `OnClickListener` set on the `ImageView` which toggles it from sliding out and in - works great.

Problem: It seems that the `ImageView` is not *actually* moving it's coordinates, but it just *looks* like it's moving.  When the `ImageView` is only partly visible(waiting to be animated out into the screen), if I click on an area where the `ImageView` would be if it were slid out, the animation starts(`OnClickListener` is fired off).

I wasn't clicking on the `ImageView`!

Question:
So, components with an animation such as this do not actually move?
How can I handle this onClick event, as it would be unexpected for an animation to occur when pressing on the screen where the `ImageView` is not visible to the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, the components don't really move, only their rendered bitmap buffer. After animating out of the screen, you can use `View.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to make it really disappear.

If your target is to have a small part of the view still visible to allow the user to slide it back on the screen, you might consider using a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Comment: but if it were to really disappear, the toggling effect i want will no longer be available for the user(visually). they won't know they can click it again.  once the animation is complete it will essentially be gone for good!

Comment: Maybe should you use a SlidingDrawer widget ? (updated my answer)

Comment: I found the `SlidingDrawer` widget to be very limiting as to what you can make it do.  seems impossible to change which direction it slides, using a more complex `handle`, positioning the widget where you want, etc

Comment: Ok I understand what you want to achieve now. So you have to find a way to rearrange your layout so that your ImageView, or maybe another one containing only a part of the Bitmap, appears on the side of the screen...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create your own animation that actually moves the ImageView, that way you'll always be able to click it.

Of course it will depend on your circumstance, but say you wanted to move the image view on the X axis by adjusting the left margin, you would have something like:

```
public class ViewLeftMarginAnimation extends Animation {
    int startMargin;
    int targetMargin;
    View view;

    public ViewGrowAnimation(View view, int start, int target) {
        this.view = view;
        this.start = height;
        this.targetHeight = toHeight;
        this.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        this.setDuration(1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newMargin = (int) (startMargin + ((targetMargin - startMargin) * interpolatedTime));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.leftMargin = newMargin;
        view.setLayoutParams(p);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```