# Button not working after TranslateAnimation ends

Tags: android, animation

Im tring to simulate a slideup animation.The idea is to slideup and slidedown the tablelayout with the id searchForm when pressing the button so that i can use the extra space for a list. I managed to slideup the searchForm and the button and the list seems to be visible but after this i cant click the button, here's the code responsible for the slideup animatio:

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
  -findViewById(R.id.searchForm).getHeight());
   slide.setDuration(500);
   slide.setFillAfter(true);
   findViewById(R.id.searchForm).startAnimation(slide);
   findViewById(R.id.listBut).startAnimation(slide);

adapterSearch.add(new NotificationEntry("","444/2010","TEste","Etapa de teste2","2010"));
```

Here's the xml that has the view elements:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/search"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableLayout  android:id="@+id/searchForm"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
 android:stretchColumns="1">
 <TableRow android:paddingTop="5px">
  <TextView android:text="Nº Processo:" />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/processNr" />
 </TableRow>
 <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#B5B5B5" 
  android:layout_height="1px"
  android:paddingBottom="2px">
 </View>
 <TableRow android:paddingTop="5px">
  <TextView android:text="Etapa:" />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/tasksearch" />
 </TableRow>
 <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#B5B5B5" 
  android:layout_height="1px"
  android:paddingBottom="2px">
 </View>
 <TableRow android:paddingTop="5px">
  <TextView android:text="Data inicio:" 
   android:id="@+id/datepick" />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/datebegvalue" />
 </TableRow>
 <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#B5B5B5" 
  android:layout_height="1px"
  android:paddingBottom="2px" 
  android:paddingTop="5px">
 </View>
 <TableRow android:paddingTop="5px">
  <TextView android:text="Data Fim:" 
   android:id="@+id/dateendpick" />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/dateendvalue" />
 </TableRow>
 <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#B5B5B5" 
  android:layout_height="1px"
  android:paddingBottom="2px" 
  android:paddingTop="5px">
 </View>  
</TableLayout>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/listBut">
 <TableRow android:paddingTop="5px">
   <Button android:id="@+id/send" 
    android:text="Procurar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </TableRow>
 <ListView android:id="@+id/processlistsearch"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the views which are animating are not actually moving their x,y points, but you just visually see their movement through an animation. the views are actually still in their original position

[see my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807120/animations-how-should-i-translate-an-imageview-out-of-into-visibility-on-the-scr)

Maybe place a `GONE` view in the location where your animation ends, and when the animation ends change the visibility to `VISIBLE`.  it would appear as though it *actually* moved, and any action on the view such as a click event on a button could be used to do what you want

Comment: What do you mean? in the xml file?

Comment: yes place a button or whichever view you want(in xml) where the destination of your animation is. once that animation is over, make the button visible so a user can click it

Comment: Ive managed to make this work, but there's a blink effect when the animation ends that seems to be applied to the button.

Comment: Do you know a way to shift(move them to the "right" xy coordinates) all the views after a translation?